# R/exams: Open-ended questions with exams2moodle

Tags: moodle, r-exams

My goal is to create a question using R/exams and Moodle including a few plots generated in the Rmd exercise file. The students should describe the plots verbally and then the exercise is graded manually.

Is it possible to use `exams2moodle` to create such an open-ended free text question for Moodle? There is no extype for it. In the documentation the only hint is:
*"In order to generate free text questions in moodle one may specify extra parameters via `\exextra`. Currently the following options are supported:"*.

I have tried to add `\exextra` parameters to the metainformation, but it did not change anything.

Comment: good to see an r-exams tag. An #rstats and/or e-learning might be the better promotion though @Achim Zeileis

Comment: I created the tag as `exams` (not `r-exams`) with the following description that is still in place: _Questions related to the computer-based generation of exams (e.g., for classical written exams or e-learning platforms like Moodle) in particular with the R package "exams"._ But given that almost all postings were about R/exams, someone (not me) decided to add the `r-exams` synonym and make that the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A worked example can be found in the `essayreg` exercise shipped within the package, see: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/

And you are right that this is not very well documented. The reason is that we have used somewhat different `exextra` tags for the Moodle export and for the QTI 2.1 export. We habe to improve and unify that in one of the next R/exams versions.

Also, another pointer, in case this is useful to anyone reading the question: Another useful strategy for asking about the interpretation of (statistical) graphics is in multiple-choice format. Let the participants judge some statements about the graphic that can either be approximately correct or clearly wrong. Of course, with open-ended question you can catch more nuances but with multiple-choice questions you can automatically assess a much larger number of participants. Or participants can self-assess in practice quizzes etc. Examples for this are the `boxplots` and `scatterplot` exercises:

- http://www.R-exams.org/templates/boxplots/
- http://www.R-exams.org/templates/scatterplot/